Vector Field of Vector Bundle: Linear Implies Linear Flows

Exercise 1.26: (Olver's Equivalence, Invariance, and Symmetry) Let $E$ be a vector bundle with local coordinates $(x,y) = (x^1,\dots, x^m,y^1,\dots, y^q)$. Show that a vector field on $E$ depending linearly on the $y$ coordinates,
\begin{equation*}v = \sum_{i=1}^m \xi^i(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} + \sum_{j,k=1}^q \eta_j^k(x) y^j \frac{\partial}{\partial y^k} \end{equation*}
has a linear flow exp($tv)(x,y) = (\chi_t(x), \psi_t(x)y)$ in these variables.

To me it is clear that since $v$ is linear in induced basis given the local coordinate system on the vector bundle, we have that
\begin{equation*}
\exp(tv)(x,y) = \exp\biggr(t\biggr(\sum_{i=1}^m \xi^i(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} + \sum_{j,k=1}^q \eta_j^k(x) y^j) \frac{\partial}{\partial y^k}\biggr)\biggr) 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
= \biggr(\exp\biggr(t\biggr(\sum_{i=1}^m \xi^i(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\biggr)\biggr), \exp\biggr(t\biggr(\sum_{j,k=1}^q \eta_j^k(x) y^j) \frac{\partial}{\partial y^k}\biggr)\biggr).
\end{equation*}
In words, because of the linearity of the vector field, we may break it into the components corresponding with the local coordinates (since the induced basis vectors $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y^i}$ correspond with the local coordiantes).
Now, I argue to myself that the first coordinate makes sense with some function $\chi_t(x)$ where the argument is an inital condition, and I'm thinking of the first coordinate as the flow generated by the vector field when just considering the first sum - i.e. as just the solution to
\begin{equation*}
\frac{dx^i}{dt} = \xi^i(x) \quad \forall i \in [m].
\end{equation*}
However, I'm having trouble translating the second coordinate into an ODE such that I get what I want (perhaps this reflects never taking an ODE course). I'm getting stumped by the change of variables $\eta_j^k(x)$ as well and how to interpret. Perhaps it should be clear from the vector bundle structure.
Any hints or clarifications will be helpful! Thank you
